How to Force authentication with Windows Hello for Business in Azure AD OIDC?
Problem
We have an application registered with single sign-on in Azure AD and have implemented step-up authentication using Authentication Context and Conditional Access Policies.
The Conditional Access Policy is configured to use Windows Hello for Business (WHfB) only in Authentication Strength, ensuring that users authenticate with WHfB for specific areas of the application. This setup works perfectly when we challenge Azure AD OIDC with the authentication context. Users receive an error if WHfB authentication cannot be completed.
However, we encounter an issue when we “force re-authentication” by using max_age=0 or prompt=login as parameters in the OIDC request. In this case, users are prompted for their password and redirected to the default password + MFA authentication flow, which does not satisfy the “Authentication Strength” of WHfB only.
Screenshots from the flow are attached for reference.


Currently, users can click “Sign in with another account,” then “Other ways to sign in,” and select “Use Windows Hello or a security key.” Still, this process is impractical and difficult to explain to end-users.
Question:
Does Microsoft support any hints for selecting a specific authentication method, or is there a setting in Azure AD that can help enforce WHfB authentication specifically when forcing re-authentication? It seems the problem arises only during forced re-authentication.

you can add &acr_values=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer:windowsHello to the OIDC request to enforce WHfB authentication when forcing re-authentication.
Note that the acr_values parameter is not supported by all identity providers.

Thanks for your feedback, but urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer:windowsHello don't seem to exist in Microsoft Entra ID. I can't any documentation for that given ACR value. Can you guide me in the right direction?
